# I want to create a computed column based off a substring of another column in SQL

Tags: calculated-columns, computed-field

I have a column called TAG_

Data in the TAG_ column could like the below:

STV-123456

TV-12456

ME-666666

I want to create two computed columns

One that shows the first part of TAG_ before the hyphen

STV

TV

ME

One that shows the second part of TAG_ after the hyphen

123456

12456

666666

This shouldn't be hard but the light bulb is not on yet. Please help.

Comment: Exact syntax is likely dependent of the DBMS you are using, tag your post with the one you have in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(TAG_ ,0,CHARINDEX('-',TAG_ ,0)) AS before,
SUBSTRING(TAG_ ,CHARINDEX('-',TAG_ ,0)+1,LEN(TAG_ )) AS after from testtable
```

and the result:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Example for MySQL, syntax is likely different for other vendors:

```
create table t 
( tag_ text not null
, fst text generated always as (substr(tag_, 1, locate('-', tag_)-1)) stored
, snd text generated always as (substr(tag_, locate('-', tag_)+1)) stored
);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jkPo1V-_)